# How to make a resizable chess board?

Tags: graphics, homework, recreational-mathematics

For some reason I need to create a chess board. I can create a chess board by following command:

```
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[Thick], Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}],
  EdgeForm[Thick], White, Rectangle[{1, 0}],
  EdgeForm[Thick], , Black, Rectangle[{2, 0}],

  EdgeForm[Thick], White, Rectangle[{0, 1}],
  EdgeForm[Thick], Black, Rectangle[{1, 1}],
  EdgeForm[Thick], White, Rectangle[{2, 1}],

  EdgeForm[Thick], Black, Rectangle[{0, 2}],
  EdgeForm[Thick], White, Rectangle[{1, 2}],
  EdgeForm[Thick], , Black, Rectangle[{2, 2}],

  }]
```

Problem is it has to be resizable (`Manipulate` command). And I should put the numbers for columns and rows. I am going to give one parameter such as board size. The code will generate the board. I believe there is a code for that, but I couldn't find on the internet. Thanks for the help.

This is an example, chess board.

[image: Example chess board]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Manipulate[MatrixPlot[Table[Mod[i + j, 2], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}], ColorFunction -> "Monochrome"], {{n, 8}, 1, 20}]
```

[image]

Nice and simple.

To make it a little more terse we can use [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Array.html) in place of [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html):

```
Manipulate[MatrixPlot[Plus ~Array~ {n, n} ~Mod~ 2, ColorFunction -> "Monochrome"], {{n, 8}, 1, 20}]
```

With correct column numbering, thanks to a shameless steal from Kuba:

```
Manipulate[
 MatrixPlot[Table[Mod[i + j, 2], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}], 
  ColorFunction -> "Monochrome", 
  FrameTicks -> {Range@n,Transpose[{#, FromCharacterCode /@ (# + 96)} &[Range[n]]]}], {{n, 8}, 1, 20}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. :) Now, I need to put queen pictures some of the squares. Is there any quick way to do it?

Comment: You could use Show[]

Comment: @user14114 `\[WhiteQueen]` and `\[BlackQueen]` are the characters you need.

Comment: I didn't know these commands. Thanks for these commands. However, I need queens on the board. How can I put queens together with background?

Comment: This answer doesn't quite do what O.P. asked/showed: still need letters rather than numbers to label columns; index origin for vertical labels to be at bottom; and squares gray instead of black (so that chess pieces would show when on the dark squares).

Comment: @murray The OP states, "And I should put the numbers for columns and rows."  And this answer was accepted.  The image the OP used as an example is taken from the web, I would guess, and does not represent a strict requirement.

Comment: There are queens on this board, but it's not resizable: [chessboard](https://www.dropbox.com/s/44q5gn6sug119r5/chessboard.nb?dl=0)

Comment: @Michael E2: sorry, I missed that. I've never seen chess notation where both columns and rows are numbers. The standard, so far as I recall, for chess literature is what I said.

Answer (score 12):

For even n:

```
MatrixPlot[
 ArrayPad[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}], 3, "Reflected"],
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

Comment: Clever use of `ArrayPad`!

Comment: @eldo,Can your solution extend to other integer like 5,6,9 etc?

Comment: @ShutaoTANG I tried some alternative approaches where Method 2 uses ArrayPad while Method 1 tries to be as succint as possible, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95577/2000. Method 1 has a similar issue as with eldo such that the colour traversal by one due to different oddity. Method 2 does not have this issue.

Answer (score 8):

My answer:

```
cb[n_Integer /; n > 0] := MatrixPlot@SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> Mod[i + j, 2], {n, n}]

cb[8]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

For those who desire a more traditional board:

```
Block[{n = 8},
 MatrixPlot[
  SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> Mod[1 + i + j, 2], {n, n}],
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
  FrameTicks -> {
    {#, #} &@ Table[{i, n - i + 1}, {i, n}],
    {#, #} &@ Table[{i, FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode["a"] + i - 1]}, {i, n}]},
  FrameStyle -> Bold
  ]
 ]
```

---

Thanks to [@eldo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58690/how-to-build-a-game-board), someone answered this question and bumped it to the top of the stack.  I had seen it about an hour before when I referred @eldo to it, but I ignored it until it came to the top of the stack.  Now we have several answers to both, each of which might be an answer to the other.

Comment: You should of course notice that in chess one uses different labels.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick I did notice.  But I also noticed the accepted answer.  Which does the OP want?  What is the standard chess labelling for a 30 x 30 board?

Comment: Well, I don't know, but a chess board is a chess board:) In the question example it is ok.

Comment: `ArrayMesh[]` can be used in newer versions as well: `ArrayMesh[SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> Mod[i + j, 2], {8, 8}], MeshCellStyle -> Black]`

Answer (score 5):

This is one of those problems that has many solutions:

```
cb[n_] := MatrixPlot[
  Range@ConstantArray[n, n] + Range[n],
  ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel@Mod[1 + #, 2] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotRangePadding -> None,
  FrameTicks -> {
   {#, #} &@ Table[{i, n - i + 1, 0}, {i, n}],
   {#, #} &@ Table[{i, FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode["a"] + i - 1], 0}, {i, n}]},
  FrameStyle -> Bold]

cb[8]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Other ways to generate the matrix:

```
Apply[Plus, Outer[List, Range[n], Range[n]], {2}],
Total[Outer[List, Range[n], Range[n]], {-1}],
```

Answer (score 3):

#### My solution

```
ChessBoard[n_?IntegerQ] := MatrixPlot[
Flatten[
 Table[
 {Flatten@Table[{1, 0}, {n}], 
 RotateLeft[Flatten@Table[{1, 0}, {n}], 1]}, {n}], 1],
 ColorFunction -> "Monochrome"]

Manipulate[ChessBoard[n], {n, 2, 5, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1. 63 chars (and 39 without beautifying to black-white)**

This considers the system as graph traversal where the number of steps is the sum and each step you wear different suit.

[image: 63 chars]

**Method 2. 87 chars with Array manipulation (63)**

I remixed Eldo's idea about reflection, better idea is probably to find a command to repeat a pattern like *"repeat 10 N amount of times and fill the array with the content"*

[image]

and the good side of this method is that you can very easily get different kinds of boards by changing oddity

[image]

and to be enough enterntaining: Method 2 results into jail stripes with even number :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution, inclusive labeling.

```
Manipulate[
 MatrixPlot[Table[If[EvenQ[i + j], 1, 0], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}], 
  FrameTicks -> Transpose[{#, {#, CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[#]]}} & /@ Range[n]],
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"], {{n, 8}, 1, 26}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Mod[Array[Plus, {9, 9}], 2] // Image // ImageResize[#, 300] &
```

[image]

```
Mod[Array[Plus, {9, 9}], 2] // Raster // Graphics (* or *)
Graphics @ Raster[Mod[+##, 2]& ~ Array ~ {9, 9}]
```

[image]