# Chess in Mathematica

Tags: packages, game

Is there a *Mathematica* chess package?
I'm trying to generate GIFs from chess PGNs. Additionally, I like to try some chess algorithms against a chess engine and watch the game and run statistical analysis on hundreds of games. I don't want to write everything from scratch but I don't know where to search for third party *Mathematica* packages.

Comment: A chess related visualization can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47591/731). Packages can be found [here](http://packagedata.net/), but there doesn't seem to be any chess package there.

Comment: @C.E. There now exists a chess package at http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/search/365/Chess

Answer (score 5):

Wolfram Language 13.2 has a built-in preliminary support for chess. You can import PGN files and FEN strings, render positions as graphics, process game metadata, display dynamic game summary and more.

Generating a GIF of a chess game from PGN file is straightforward:

```
In[1]:= positions = Import["ExampleData/sample.pgn", {"PositionRenderingList", 1}];

In[2]:= Export["game.gif", positions]

Out[2]= "game.gif"
```

By default chess positions are rendered to a Graphics expression which looks like this

[image: white and gray chessboard]

If you don't like the default white and gray chessboard or you want to flip the board there are options for customization, e.g.:

[image: flipped board with different square colors]

You can also import game metadata with dates, times and famous players being automatically interpreted as corresponding Wolfram Language expressions or entities:

[image: import PGN metadata]

For more information see:

- PGN reference page: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/PGN
- FEN reference page: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/FEN