# How to print chess board with array?

Tags: programming

I am doing n-queen implementation with my own algorithm and I get solutions with Number.But,I want to get output with actual chess board.

This is my piece of code.

```
solutions(* array *)

MatrixForm[solutions]

MatrixForm[{{2,8,9,15},{3,5,12,14}}].
```

I want to know how to print to combine with GUI chess board by using my solutions array.
Number represents positions of chess board.
I am new to mathematica. Thanks.

---

@David Is this code work for dynamic array?My solutions is for the size of n=4 and get 2 solutions.

Comment: I actually trouble in plz

Comment: Related: [164930](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164930/how-to-create-a-game-board-in-mathematica-edited/164948#164948), [47590](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47590/how-to-put-some-number-of-queens-on-chess-board-dynamically/47591#47591)

Answer (score 3):

```
Graphics[
 Table[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{1, 1}, {9, 9}], 
   FaceForm[If[OddQ[i + j], White, Black]], 
   Rectangle[{i, j}, {i + 1, j + 1}],
   FaceForm[Red], Disk[{3.5, 4.5}, .5], Disk[{5.5, 7.5}, .5]}, 
   {i, 1, 8, 1}, {j, 1, 8, 1}]
 ]
```

[image]

Your `MatrixForm[{{2,8,9,15},{3,5,12,14}}]` makes no sense.

Comment: Is this code work for dynamic array?My solutions is for the size of n=4 and get 2 solutions.

Comment: @ThuriyaThwin  have included a dynamic option.  Very primitive but will get you started to something mode robust.

Answer (score 0):

To do dymanic chess

```
Manipulate[Graphics[
 Table[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{1, 1}, {9, 9}], 
   FaceForm[If[OddQ[i + j], White, Black]], 
   Rectangle[{i, j}, {i + 1, j + 1}],
   FaceForm[Red], Disk[{4.5+.5*moveX, 4.5+.5*moveY}, .5], Disk[{5.5+.5*move2X, 7.5+.5*move2Y}, .5]}, 
   {i, 1, 8, 1}, {j, 1, 8, 1}]
 ],{moveX,-6,8},{moveY,-6,8},{move2X,-8,6},{move2Y,-12,2}]
```